# Django inner join to a model without directly relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

i need to join a table without a direct relationship.

models.py:

```py
class FooModel():
  bar = ForeignKey(Bar)

class BarModel():
  pass

class BazModel():
  bar = ForeignKey(Bar)

class QuxModel():
  foo = ForeignKey(Foo)
```

tried to reach Foo from Baz but didn't work

viewset.py:

```py
def BazView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  queryset = model.BazModel.objects.all().prefetch_related('bar').prefetch_related('baz__bar')
  serializer_class = serializer.Baz

  def get_queryset(self):
    return self.queryset
```

serializer.py

```
class FooSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = FooModel
    exlude = []

class BarSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = BarModel
    exlude = []

class BazSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
  foo = FooSerializer()

  class Meta:
    model = BarModel
    exlude = []

class QuxSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = QuxModel
    exlude = []
```

using `prefetch` like that i got an error saying that Baz has no foo field.

also would like to get data from QuxModel based on Foo FK...

how could i perform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
model.BazModel.objects.all().select_related('bar').prefetch_related('bar__foomodel_set')
```

And then in `BazSerializer`, you can set the `source` for `foo` like this:

```py
class BazSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    foo = FooSerializer(source='bar.foomodel_set')
```

This will tell the `foo` serializer to get it's data from the `FooModel` objects using `BazModel`'s `bar`.

You might have to change `foomodel_set` to the related name you have set to access `FooModel` from  `BarModel`.

Comment: it worked for me. Thanks!